Assign "track_id" to each time interval (using minimum number of "track_id"s) so that no intervals with the same "track_id" overlap
I have a table of intervals with the columns: "id", "start_ts", "duration".
How can I write a SQLite query which can assign a "track_id" to each interval so that no intervals sharing the same "track_id" overlap, while using a minimum number of possible "track_id"s?
Conceptually, the problem is quite simple when imagined procedurally. To implement this procedurally, I would simply do (pseudocode):
nextTrackId = 0
# Iterate through each interval
for interval in intervals:
  # Add the interval to an existing track if possible
  addedToExistingTrack = False
  for track in tracks:
    if interval.doesNotOverlapWithAnyIntervalsIn(track):
      interval.track_id = track.id  # assign the interval's track_id to the track's id
      track.add(interval)
      addedToExistingTrack = True
      break

  # Otherwise, create a new track
  if !addedToExistingTrack:
    newTrack = Track(id = nextTrackId++)
    interval.track_id = newTrack.id  # assign the interval's track_id to the new track's id
    newTrack.add(interval)
    tracks.add(newTrack)

However, I am struggling with how I can implement this declaratively in SQLite (3.35.4).
I have tried doing this through recursive CTEs. However, I keep running into a need for either a recursive aggregate query or recursive window function or multiple recursive references to the recursive CTE, none of which are supported in SQLite (at least, not my version of SQLite - 3.35.4).  Perhaps I'm just unable to imagine the proper way to set this up using recursive CTEs. Or perhaps recursive CTEs aren't the answer at all and there is a simpler way.
